# Deleting related records in Laravel 5.1 (Eloquent ORM)

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.1, relationship

I have **customers** model, which hasMany **Locations**, and **Locations** hasMany **contacts**.

I want to delete the Customer and all its locations and  contacts.

Now below code removes the locations successfully :

```
$customer = Customer::find($id);
$customer->locations()->delete();
```

But I want to remove the Contacts as well.

Ideally I want the code like :

```
$customer->locations()->contacts()->delete();
```

Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

You could set this up in your migrations by specifying the `onDelete('cascade')` in your pivot table, take a look at **[foreign-key-constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)**, e.g :

```
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Or use **[eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events)**, what you want in this case is the "deleting" event to do the cleanup.

Customer Model :

```
class Customer extends Eloquent
{
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($customer) { 
             $customer->locations()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

Location Model :

```
class Location extends Eloquent
{
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($location) {
             $location->contacts()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

Hopet this helps.

Comment: I am aware of foreign key constraint, but I only wanted to handle it on code level, as these constraints slows down the performance.

Comment: I have tried it but the child model not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You Could define this in your Models.

Customer Model

```
class Customer extends Eloquent
{
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Location');
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($customer) { 
             // before delete() method call this
             $customer->locations()->delete();
             // do the locations cleanup...
        });
    }
}
```

And in your Locations Model

```
class Location extends Eloquent
    {
        public function contacts()
        {
            return $this->has_many('Contact');
        }

        protected static function boot() {
            parent::boot();

            static::deleting(function($location) { 
                 // before delete() method call this
                 $location->contacts()->delete();
                 // do the contacts cleanup...
            });
        }
    }
```

And Now

```
$customer = Customer::find($id);
$customer->delete();
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: its not working, as it only deleted the locations, not the location contacts. I think it only works for one-to-many relationship, in my case there are many locations for customer and each location has multiple contacts.